# Why is there a "deadbranch" in my code?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

below my code was working fine until my last if-else. It appears I've done something wrong with my boolean variables canGraduate and onProbation. Perhaps I'm reassigning them incorrectly in the prior if-else statements. The deadbranch occurs at the else half of my last if-else.

```
package lab5;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //creates scanner object
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //PART II
    //creating variables
    double gpa;
    int totalCreditsTaken;
    int mathScienceCredits;
    int liberalArtsCredits;
    int electiveCredits;
    boolean canGraduate = true;
    boolean onProbation = false;

    //prompts user for imput
    System.out.println("What is your GPA?");
        gpa = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What's the total amount of credits you've taken?");
        totalCreditsTaken = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many math and science credits have you taken?");
        mathScienceCredits = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many liberal arts credits have you taken?");
        liberalArtsCredits = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many elective credits have you taken?");
        electiveCredits = scanner.nextInt();

    //creates first "if" statment to determine if GPA is high enough to be on track or on probation 
    if (gpa < 2.0){
        System.out.println("You're on academic probation.");
        onProbation = true;
    }

    //PART III
    //creates a conditional to see if there's enough credits to graduate 
    if (totalCreditsTaken < 40 ){
        System.out.println("You need more credit(s) to graduate.");
        canGraduate = false;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Examining credit breakdown...");
        canGraduate = true;
    }

    //PART VI
    //Nested if-else if-else to determine if the student qualifies for BA or BS
    if ((mathScienceCredits >= 9) && (electiveCredits >= 10)){
        System.out.println("You qualify for a BS degree.");
        canGraduate = true;
    }
    else if ((liberalArtsCredits >= 9) && (electiveCredits >= 10)){
        System.out.println("You qualify for a BA degree.");
        canGraduate = true;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("You currently don't meet the degree requirments.");
        canGraduate = false;
    }

    //PART V
    //Uses an if statement to either congradulate the student or tell the student to take more classes
    if ((onProbation = true) || (canGraduate = false)){
        System.out.println("You don't qualify to graduate.");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Congradualations you qualify to graduate.");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more explanation about what's happening here.

In Java, the `=` operator is *assignment*, not comparison (The comparison operator is `==`). So if `a` is an `int`, `a = 3` means "put the value 3 in the variable `a`".

But an assignment is also an expression. In addition to putting the value in that variable, the expression also evaluates to the value that was assigned.

So the value of the expression `a = 3` is 3. You can do things like:

```
System.out.println( a = 3 );
```

This will both put 3 in `a`, and print `3` on the console.

Usually, Java doesn't allow you to confuse between `=` and `==`. If the variable is an `int` or a `float` or a `String`, writing a statement like:

```
if ( a = 3 ) ... // Compilation error
```

will not work because the value of the expression is 3, an `int` value, and `if` expects an expression of type `boolean`. So it will tell you that the expression is wrong, and you'll notice: "Oh, I meant `==`".

But if the type of `a` is *`boolean`*, then writing `a = false` or `a = true` is an assignment, that also returns the value that was assigned - which is a **`boolean`**. Because of that, you can write

```
if ( a = false ) ... // Compiles correctly
```

and the compiler won't complain, because the value of the expression is `boolean` and that's what the `if` expects. The compiler doesn't know you actually meant to compare. All it knows is that it got an expression of the appropriate type.

For this reason it is recommended never to compare `boolean` variables at all. Instead of

```
if ( a == true )
```

It is perfectly correct to write

```
if ( a )
```

Because the `if` will succeed when `a` is `true` and fail when `a` is `false`. No need to compare! It's important to give the variable a good name like you did - `canGraduate` is a good name, and a statement like

```
if ( canGraduate )
```

is nicely readable "If [the user] can graduate...".

For `false`, you can use

```
if ( ! canGraduate )
```

it's not as nice-sounding in English, but it's clear enough, and clearer than `if ( canGraduate == false )`, with the added bonus that you will not miss the `=` and write `if ( canGraduate = false )` by mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is EXACTLY what I needed. I'll come back and up your post when I have 15 rep. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning the values here:

`if ((onProbation = true) || (canGraduate = false)){`

You need to compare them using `==` instead

**UPDATE (after comments)**

Better yet, don't compare boolean values.  Instead, since `onProbation` and `canGraduate` are both boolean types, you can use:

`if (onProbation || ! canGraduate ){`

credit to @RealSkeptic and @FredK (in their comments)

Comment: Actually, to prevent things like that from happening - just don't compare boolean values. `if (onProbation || ! canGraduate)` will do nicely.

Comment: Then the entire if-else statement becomes a "deadbranch".

Comment: @RealSkeptic true.  I was just pointing out the syntax error.

Comment: @AutumnPickart care to expand?  I am not sure I understand your comment

Comment: Oh I see, I'm currently using NetBeans and it's saying that I'm not using that code (a deadbranch). I want onProbation = true OR canGraduate = false. Otherwise I want the system to print something else out. @ochi

Comment: Don't compare boolean values to "true" or "false". 
Instead of "if (a == true)" you should just uses "if (a):

Comment: And instead of "if (b == false)" just use "if ( !b )"